# Recursive implementation Or in Clojure

Tags: recursion, clojure

I'm attempting to implement my own Clojure 'or' macro (called 'my-or'). So far I've got:

```
 (defmacro my-or
    [& args]
    (let [[x xs] (seq args)]
        `(if ~x ~x (my-or ~xs))))
```

However, when calling this function, for example:

```
(my-or false 4 3)
```

this causes a StackOverflowError. I appreciate what I've written is recursive, but what exactly is it about the function that causes the error? Incidentally, I've also taken a look at the official implementation of 'or' in the clojure.core library, so I'm aware of a solution that works.

(Maybe tail-recursion is relevant here? Not sure.)

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You doesn't have the base case of recursion i.e case where recursion stops:

```
(defmacro my-or
    [& args]
    (let [[x & xs] args]
      (if (nil? xs) `(if ~x ~x)
          `(if ~x ~x (my-or ~@xs)))))
```